# showViewController method only displays modal views

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, hig

Looking at Apples [Resource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/showViewController:sender:) for using `showViewController()` versus `presentViewController()` I can't seem to figure out my issue here.

I want to display a viewController from my storyboard programmatically by doing the following:

```
  if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainTab") as? TabBarController {
       showViewController(resultController, sender: UIBarButtonItem.self)
  }
```

This works fine. However, it's presentation is always modal. Covering the screen vertically from bottom to top like so:

[image: modal display]

I was/still am under the impression that I should use **showViewController** to display a screen without the animation... But clearly I'm missing something here. All I want to do is display the VC non-modally. I feel like I've tried everything to no avail.

Thanks for the advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use something like this.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Controller") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil) // no animation or presentation as modal because animated is false
```

The key is to have animated set to *false*. This method works for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Dude, you rock. Thanks.